# R: Merge of rows in same data table, concatenating certain columns

Tags: r, merge, concatenation

I have my data table in R. I want to merge rows which have an identical `customerID`, and then concatenate the elements of other merged columns.

I want to go from this:

```
   title  author customerID
1 title1 author1          1
2 title2 author2          2
3 title3 author3          1
```

to this:

```
           title           author Group.1
1 title1, title3 author1, author3       1
2         title2          author2       2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `aggregate` function should help you in finding a solution:

```
dat = data.frame(title = c("title1", "title2", "title3"),
                 author = c("author1", "author2", "author3"),
                 customerID = c(1, 2, 1))
aggregate(dat[-3], by=list(dat$customerID), c)
#   Group.1 title author
# 1       1  1, 3   1, 3
# 2       2     2      2
```

Or, just make sure you add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you are creating your data frame and you're pretty much good to go. If your data are already factored, you can use something like `dat[c(1, 2)] = apply(dat[-3], 2, as.character)` to convert them to character first, then:

```
aggregate(dat[-3], by=list(dat$customerID), c)
#   Group.1          title           author
# 1       1 title1, title3 author1, author3
# 2       2         title2          author2
```

Comment: @HarryPalmer, I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question. Assuming you had assigned the output of `aggregate` to another object, say `temp`, `temp$title` would be a list (like this `list(`0` = c("title1", "title3"), `1` = "title2")`. The `title` and `author` columns in this example are lists. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hmm I think I get it now thanks. I was confused about data types. One more question please: How can I eliminate duplicates that appear in a column/row list element after the aggregation? I tried data1 <- unique(data2$title) but curiously that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the best solution but easy to understand:

```
df <- data.frame(author=LETTERS[1:5], title=LETTERS[1:5], id=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

uniqueIds <- unique(df$id)

mergedDf <- df[1:length(uniqueIds),]

for (i in seq(along=uniqueIds)) {
    mergedDf[i, "id"] <- uniqueIds[i]
    mergedDf[i, "author"] <- paste(df[df$id == uniqueIds[i], "author"], collapse=",")
    mergedDf[i, "title"] <- paste(df[df$id == uniqueIds[i], "title"], collapse=",")
}

mergedDf
#  author title id
#1    A,C   A,C  1
#2    B,D   B,D  2
#3      E     E  3
```

Comment: Good, but R has a few inbuilt functions for dealing with grouped data. The best for this case is `aggregate(df[-3], by=list(df$id), c)`, but `by(df[-3], df$id, c)` also gives you the same result, just in a totally different format.

Comment: @mrdwab: thx, I don't use dataframes very often and didn't know the `aggregate` function.