# Combining rows of long text from Excel for text analytics use

Tags: excel, text-analysis

This is sort of related to [Outputting Excel rows to a series of text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149539/outputting-excel-rows-to-a-series-of-text-files#)

Similar to he has asked previously, I have a slightly more complex dataset on my hands.

Each row in Excel for me is a paragraph, and I have a column for the text, a column that states the document ID, as well as an order ID(smallest to largest).

I would like to concatenate the the text for each document ID together, with line breaks in between. However, some documents are so long that it will exceed the Excel character limit.

I also have a series of variables that describe the document, title, dates etc.

I have tried to use google spreadsheet or openoffice, but it does not seem to work either.

How can I perform this "vertical concatenate"? I am ok with either one huge CSV file, a collection of text files, or maybe an Access file?

Comment: Can you use R or Java?  Excel wasn't really designed with this type of problem in mind.

Comment: I am ok with R, but I am most probably going to run some NLTK from Python to do topic discovery...

Comment: Use `read.csv()` to read in the file, then have a look at articles such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364992/r-merge-of-rows-in-same-data-table-concatenating-certain-columns).