# Melting on selected columns with na.rm = T, removes the data row completely although remaining columns have valid data

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I'm a beginner in R and huge fan of data.table features in R
This is perhaps my first Question on R in the forum and apologies for any ill-formatting of the code/text.

I happen to work with a data set of large number of categorical variables
I tried to create a mock data set to explain the problem:

```
structure(list(ID = 1234:1237, 
AgeC = c("25-30", "31+", "25-30", "20-24"), 
GenderC = c("female", "male", "female", "female"), 
doyoubuyappleseveryday = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA), 
doyoubuyapplesonceinaweek = c(1L, NA, NA, NA), 
doyoubuyapplesonceinamonth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
doyoubuypearseveryday = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
doyoubuypearsonceinaweek = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), 
doyoubuypearssonceinamonth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
doyoueatappleseveryday = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
doyoueatapplesonceinaweek = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA), 
doyoueatapplesonceinamonth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
doyoueatpearseveryday = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA), 
doyoueatpearsonceinaweek = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), 
doyoueatpearsonceinamonth = c(1L, NA, NA, NA)), 
.Names = c("ID", "AgeC", "GenderC", "doyoubuyappleseveryday", 
    "doyoubuyapplesonceinaweek", "doyoubuyapplesonceinamonth", "doyoubuypearseveryday", 
    "doyoubuypearsonceinaweek", "doyoubuypearssonceinamonth", "doyoueatappleseveryday", 
    "doyoueatapplesonceinaweek", "doyoueatapplesonceinamonth", "doyoueatpearseveryday", 
    "doyoueatpearsonceinaweek", "doyoueatpearsonceinamonth"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000380788>)
```

I was trying to reshape the data set with selected columns.. using melt()/dcast()

The idea is, with a series of melt()/dcast()  operations , I can reduce the variables to 6., by creating appropriate new variables that can take the categorical values.

In the first set, I chose to eliminate the columns  which have "buy" as a match string , using melt()/dcast functions as follows :

```
id.cols.buy.m <-names(repro.dt)[-grep("buy",names(repro.dt))]
repro.buy.m<-data.table(melt(repro.dt, id.vars = id.cols.buy.m, 
                        measure.vars = grep("buy",names(repro.dt),value=T ),
                        na.rm=T,variable.name = "buy.fruit", 
                        value.name = "buy.freq"))
```

The resulting data set, drops the complete row with ID = 1236 since "buy" variables for this ID are all 'NA'. This is a loss of data to me, since in the next sequence of reshape operations with "eat" as match string, I plan to use the cleaned version of data set from previous reshape/dcast.

Something as follows :

```
#create a new variable "fruit"
repro.buy.m$fruit = apply(repro.buy.m, 1, function(u){
bool = sapply(fruit[,1], function(x) grepl(x,u[['buy.fruit']]))
if(any(bool)) fruit[bool] else NA
})


#create a fruit purchase freq column 

repro.buy.m$freq.pur= apply(repro.buy.m, 1, function(u){
bool = sapply(freq.levels[,1], function(x) grepl(x, u[['buy.fruit']]))
if(!is.na(u[['buy.freq']])) freq.levels[bool] else NA
})

#now drop the redundant colums that have "buy"  as match string--

id.cols.buy.m <- colnames(repro.buy.m)[-grep("buy",names(repro.buy.m))]
f <- as.formula(paste(paste(id.cols.buy.m, collapse = " + "), "~ buy.fruit"))

repro.buy.c<-data.table(dcast(data = repro.buy.m, f, 
                              value.var   ="buy.freq",
                              function(x)   length(unique(x))))

repro.buy.c<-repro.buy.c[, which(grepl("buy", colnames(repro.buy.c))):=NULL]
```

with the above step, all my "buy" variables -- 6 of them are now reduced to 2
***However, I lost one ID who does not buy any fruits but eats fruits***
If I do not use na.rm = T, the row is retained , however it shoots up another problem of duplicating rows when I reshape for variables with "eat" as a match string

My final goal is to merge the categorical variables with a single column called "fruit" and the associated columns "freq.pur" and "freq.eat" with NA's as applicable,and grouped by ID.

something like this (this is for a single ID) :

```
structure(list(fruit = c("apples", "pears"), freq.pur = c("onceinaweek",NA),
freq.et = c("onceinaweek", "onceinamonth")), 
.Names = c("fruit", "freq.pur", "freq.et"), 
row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000380788>, sorted = "fruit")
```

With this example data set , I would request any help on

1. How to remove NA values for the selected columns during partial and
   sequential reshaping of data -- so as to avoid duplicate rows after reshape
2. How to merge columns of different lengths within the same data table joined by a single categorical variable with unique values (in this case "fruit") , grouped by ID -- again to remove meaning-less rows

Best Regards

Edit : 04/21 : 10:15IST (mock data table for expected output)

```
structure(list(ID = c(1234L, 1234L, 1235L, 1235L, 1236L, 1237L), 
AgeC = c("25-30", "25-30", "31+", "31+", "25-30", "20-24"), 
GenderC = c("female", "female", "male", "male", "female", 
"female"), freq.pur = c(NA, "onceinaweek", "everyday", "everyday", 
NA, "onceinaweek"), freq.et = c("onceinamonth", "onceinaweek", 
"everyday", "everyday", "onceinaweek", "onceinaweek"), fruit = c("pears", 
"apples", "apples", "pears", "apples", "pears")), 
.Names = c("ID","AgeC", "GenderC", "freq.pur", "freq.et", "fruit"),
row.names = c(NA,-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
```

.internal.selfref = )

EDIT : 04/25

I was able to work on a solution for this , with the help of a few "unique" calls on the intermediate structures and few auxiliary variables, and I was able to test all the use cases. My final data table is as below :

```
dput(repro.buy.eat.final)

structure(list(ID = c(1210L, 1210L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1235L, 
1235L, 1237L, 1237L, 1238L, 1238L, 1239L), 
AgeC = c("25-30", "25-30", "25-30", "25-30", "25-30", "31+", 
"31+", "20-24", "20-24", "25-30", "25-30", "25-30"), 
GenderC = c("female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male"), 
fruit = c("apples", "apples", "apples", "pears", "apples", "apples",
"pears", "pears", "pears", "apples", "pears", "pears"), 
freq.et = c("everyday", NA, NA, "onceinamonth", "onceinaweek", NA,
"everyday", "onceinaweek", NA, "onceinamonth", NA, NA), 
freq.pur = c(NA, "onceinaweek", "onceinaweek", NA, NA, "everyday", NA, 
NA,  "onceinaweek", NA, "everyday", "onceinaweek")), 
row.names = c(NA, -12L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002830788>, 
.Names = c("ID", "AgeC", "GenderC", "fruit", "freq.et", "freq.pur"))
```

In the resulting set, I want to merge similar fruits with similar "buy" and "eat" frequencies. I found somewhat relevant answer here :
[R: Merge of rows in same data table, concatenating certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364992/r-merge-of-rows-in-same-data-table-concatenating-certain-columns),
however, I did not know how to apply a condition to match the frequencies, although I can group by ID and fruits. 
I'm looking for some help here.
I could share the code snippets here.. if this post had not become so long. I'm yet to get a hold on the formatting style to append the data table in the tabular view.

The test cases, I used :

1. did not buy fruits , but ate fruits-
2. did not eat fruits, but bought fruits
3. buy and eat same fruits same freq
4. buy and eat same fruits different freq
5. buy and eat diff fruits same freq
6. buy and eat diff fruits diff freq

Best Regards

Comment: A couple of questions.  Can you provide an example of your expected output from the input?  Also  for each group of items (say buy apples daily, weekly or monthly) is there only 1 answer or could there be more?  My thoughts are to melt each group of 3 down into separate dataframes, eliminate the NA rows and then merge all of the dataframes together with outer_join from the dplyr package using the unique ID column.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. In your Q1 : do you want me to provide expected output at the end of each reshape operation? for.e.g what goes into melt and what comes out of it or into dcast() and out of dcast(), -- and how to attach an expected output to this comment??To answer your Q2: Each ID can have multiple answers, would it be 12 combinations of answers possible for each ID.."- hope I'm not misleading.

Comment: If you could edit your question and add what the final expected output should look like. this would allow someone to work from the start and have a defined endpoint.  My second question concerns each group of questions.  Would you expect (or allow) a particular ID to buyapplesdaily and buyapplesweekly?

Comment: The answer to your second Q is : either buy apples daily or buy apples weekly or monthly. I will edit my Q later to add the expected output.Thanks again.

Comment: @Dave2e. I edited my Q for expected o/p. BTW, on your approach of merge.. I thin 2 data frames are sufficient. However, when the merge is kind of right outer join, the result will have NA values for those rows that are not in the LHS df.. This is unwanted because, the mandatory variables like ID/AgeC/GenderC. also become NA. We may have to code a specific logic to impute their original values.. I'm still short at my understanding of merge in R. Thanks again, Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. Assuming your `data.table` is called `dt`:

**Step 1:**

Change your column names in a way we can split on them later:

```
setnames(dt, gsub("doyou(buy|eat)(apples|pears)", "\\1_\\2_", names(dt)))
```

The `\\1` and `\\2` *captures* the values provided in paranthesis `()` in the first argument of `gsub`. Basically I've added `_` where I wanted so that the names are now:

```
names(dt)
#  [1] "ID"                      "AgeC"                    "GenderC"                
#  [4] "buy_apples_everyday"     "buy_apples_onceinaweek"  "buy_apples_onceinamonth"
#  [7] "buy_pears_everyday"      "buy_pears_onceinaweek"   "buy_pears_sonceinamonth"
# [10] "eat_apples_everyday"     "eat_apples_onceinaweek"  "eat_apples_onceinamonth"
# [13] "eat_pears_everyday"      "eat_pears_onceinaweek"   "eat_pears_onceinamonth"
```

Now we can split on `_`. I'd recommend to use separators always for easy reading as well.

**Step 2:**

Melt your data.table:

```
dt.m = melt(dt, id=names(dt)[1:3])
```

Read the warning and try to understand it. It warns because some of your columns are all `NA` (which were loaded as *logical* type, as opposed to *integer* type). That's fine here, since the end result is *integer* column. So you can ignore the warning.

**Step 3:**

*Split* the *variable* column on `_` and create 3 *separate* columns:

```
dt.m[, c("buy_eat", "fruit", "freq") := tstrsplit(variable, "_", fixed=TRUE)]
dt.m[, variable := NULL]
```

`:=` takes a character vector (for column names) on the `LHS` and  a *list* for corresponding values in the `RHS`. `tstrsplit` already returns a *list*. Check the output of `tstrsplit(...)` separately by doing: `tstrsplit(dt.m$variable, "_", fixed=TRUE)` to understand what it is doing.

`:= NULL` removes the column. We don't need `variable` anymore. So we remove it. When LHS is a single value, we don't necessarily have to provide the `""` for convenience, i.e., `"variable"` and `variable` mean the same here.

**Step 4:**

Where `value` is `NA`, replace `value` with `0` and `freq` with `NA`:

```
dt.m[is.na(value), c("value", "freq") := list(0, NA)]
```

**Step 5:**

For each `ID, buy_eat, fruit`, extract the row corresponding to the maximum `value`.

```
ans = dt.m[, .SD[which.max(value)], by=.(ID, buy_eat, fruit)]
#       ID buy_eat  fruit  AgeC GenderC value         freq
#  1: 1234     buy apples 25-30  female     1  onceinaweek
#  2: 1235     buy apples   31+    male     1     everyday
#  3: 1236     buy apples 25-30  female     0           NA
#  4: 1237     buy apples 20-24  female     0           NA
#  5: 1234     buy  pears 25-30  female     0           NA
#  6: 1235     buy  pears   31+    male     0           NA
#  7: 1236     buy  pears 25-30  female     0           NA
#  8: 1237     buy  pears 20-24  female     1  onceinaweek
#  9: 1234     eat apples 25-30  female     1  onceinaweek
# 10: 1235     eat apples   31+    male     0           NA
# 11: 1236     eat apples 25-30  female     1  onceinaweek
# 12: 1237     eat apples 20-24  female     0           NA
# 13: 1234     eat  pears 25-30  female     1 onceinamonth
# 14: 1235     eat  pears   31+    male     1     everyday
# 15: 1236     eat  pears 25-30  female     0           NA
# 16: 1237     eat  pears 20-24  female     1  onceinaweek
```

`which.max(<all_NA_values>)` returns `integer(0)` (a length-0 integer), which is undesirable. This is why we replaced `value` to `0` where it's `NA` in the previous step.

**Final step:**

`dcast` it.

```
ans = dcast(ans, ID + AgeC + GenderC + fruit ~ buy_eat, value.var="freq")
#      ID  AgeC GenderC  fruit         buy          eat
# 1: 1234 25-30  female apples onceinaweek  onceinaweek
# 2: 1234 25-30  female  pears          NA onceinamonth
# 3: 1235   31+    male apples    everyday           NA
# 4: 1235   31+    male  pears          NA     everyday
# 5: 1236 25-30  female apples          NA  onceinaweek
# 6: 1236 25-30  female  pears          NA           NA
# 7: 1237 20-24  female apples          NA           NA
# 8: 1237 20-24  female  pears onceinaweek  onceinaweek
```

I think this is the result you're looking for. If not, I think this should have given you some idea on how to approach the problem. I'll leave the rest of the tinkering to you.

Comment: Thanks Arun, why should the result have duplicates for ID = 1236? When the ID does not buy or eat.. that row may not be useful.

Comment: Arun, I was going through your steps in detail now. Your Steps3,4 are definitely a learning to me.. (I'm unable to give a +1 as of now-- due a low reputation ..) However, your step1 may not be practical when I data of 1539 variables.. which means, it may not be practical to melt all 1500+ variables.